# Why procedure throws error if I pass it date i.e. 20/04/2020?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am using this

```
CAST(NotifDate as date) between @FromNotifDate AND @ToNotifDate
```

but **NotifDate** is saved as **varchar** in table but **FromNotifDate** AND **ToNotifDate** are of **Date** type.

When I pass these parameters `08/06/2014 and 20/04/2020 09:40:17` it doesn't work and throws error i.e.

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

but if I pass `08/06/2014 and 10/04/2020 09:40:17` it works.

Comment: Check your locale (culture / language) your sql server is using. American English (en-US) is using `MM/dd/yyyy` so `08/06/2014` and `10/04/2014` are valid dates (6th of August and 4th of October), but not `20/04/2020`, you are probably siwtching days and months here, should be `04/20/2020`. Note that if you use ISO 8601 (`yyyy-MM-dd`), I think SQL server will always parse the date correctly.

Comment: but is there any way to handle it without changing culture etc?

Comment: From what you're describing it seems that `@ToNotifDate` is not of type `Date` but a string... Anyway, you should strive to avoid using strings (`varchar/nvarchar/char/nchar`) to store date and datetime values. This will only cause problems.

Comment: I agree the proper course here is to properly input the date in the database if possible, as Zohar suggested. As workaround for your problem, you can use `CONVERT` and the the correct style code, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 , so in your case I assume it would be 103 : `CONVERT(date, NotifDate, 103)`.

Comment: @Pac0: put in answer's box and will accept as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current database locale settings are probably set to `en-US` or another where the date format is `MM/dd/yyyy`.

That makes `08/06/2014` and `10/04/2014` valid dates (but they are 6th of August and 4th of October, **not** 8th of June and 10th of April!), but not `20/04/2020`.

To use a different date format, you can use `CONVERT`, with the proper style code (I believe it's 103 for `dd/MM/yyyy` (see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15))

So, this should work for you : `CONVERT(date, NotifDate, 103)`

Note that, as a general recommendation, it would be beneficial that you input `NotifDate` as a proper SQL Date in your DB in the first place, if possible, to avoid having to do conversion like this in your queries.

Also, there the unambiguous and international standard ISO-8601 format `yyyy-MM-dd` which should be always parsed correctly by `CAST`, I recommend using it over any localized format where you can in your code infrastructure.

Answer (score 3):

System having default date format is "MM/dd/yyyy" so while you set "10/04/2020 09:40:17" value so system throm an Error- out of range Error,

```
-- The conversion of a varchar data type 
-- to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
select cast('20/04/2020 09:40:17'  as datetime)     

-- get the current session date_format
select date_format
from sys.dm_exec_sessions
where session_id = @@spid

-- set the dateformat for the current session
set dateformat dmy

-- this should work
select cast('20/04/2020 09:40:17'  as datetime)
```